# can we change size(width) of facebook like token input?

Tags: jquery-tokeninput

I am using facebook like token input and I want to change its width according to my textbox .

```
$("input#receiver_id").tokenInput("add", {id : jsonData.id, first_name: jsonData.firstname, last_name: jsonData.lastname}); 
//Token input---------------
    $("#receiver_id").tokenInput(PROJECT_URL+PROJECT_NAME+"mail/get-my-matching-contacts", {
        onAdd: function (item) {
            $("div#receiver_ids_holder").append("<input type = 'hidden' name = 'receiver_ids[]' class = 'receiver_ids' id = '"+item.id+"' value = '"+item.id+"'>");
            $("#jq_receiver_id").attr('placeholder','');
        },
        onDelete: function (item) {
            $('div#receiver_ids_holder input#'+item.id).remove();
        }, 
        theme: "facebook",
        propertyToSearch: "first_name",
        propertyToSearch: "last_name",
        resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li><div style = 'width:25px; height:25px; display:inline-block;margin:0 0 4px 0;'><div style = 'width:25px; height:25px; display : table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;'>" + "<img style = 'max-width : 25px; max-height : 25px;' src='" + item.url + "' title='" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "'/></div></div>" + "<div style='display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;'><div class='full_name'>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "</div><div class='email'>" + item.email + "</div></div></li>" },
        tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "</p></li>" },
    });
```

i have tried to give width in its css but it didn't worked . 
Need some immediate help with this.

Comment: What did you try to give a width with CSS. Can you post that bit of code?

Comment: @chris div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook{ width : 100%; }

Answer (score 2):

I add this style on my html doc and worked for me .Here is the [link](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/98) to customize dropdown list if you are interested.

```
<style>
ul.token-input-list-facebook
{
   width:100%;
}
</style>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("ul").css({"width":"100%";});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just the style tag worked for me, didn't need the script tag.